# Is this how you PCB trace a 50 ohm impedance transmission line for an RF antenna?

Tags: rf, pcb-design, antenna

I am trying to use LoRa with a RFM95W module. I added this 3mm trace on the opposite side of the ground plane to try to create a 50-ohm impedance. I want to use a wire antenna to J4. I also included an optional ufl antenna connector. Does this look like the correct way to lay this out? Is there enough of a cutout of ground pour around the trace?
[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you want a coplanar waveguide.  As for your antenna - is that just a piece of wire???

Comment: No, it doesn't. The calculator you used assumes that there's a ground plane. But in your application, there's not.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Sorry I should have mentioned the Top layer (red) will have a ground pour

Comment: @Kartman Yes, unless I go with the UFL connected antenna, I plan to try a single wire monopole antenna or perhaps a helix wire

Comment: You’ll need a 4 layer board with your current layout. The rf signal needs to be surrounded by ground. With your current layout, rf will find its way into miso of the esp32 and elsewhere.